# Monad State And get function

Tags: haskell

```
type InterpreterMonad  = StateT (Env, Env) (ErrorT String IO ) ()    

interpreter :: Stmts -> InterpreterMonad
interpreter (Statements s EmptyStmts) = interpreteStmt s
interpreter (Statements s stmts) = interpreteStmt s >>= \m -> (interpreter stmts)


-- definicja funkcji

interpreteStmt :: Stmt -> InterpreterMonad 
interpreteStmt (DefFun  (VarName name) args typ begin statements end) = get >>= 
    \(envOut, (sInnerEnvFun, sInnerEnvEVal)) -> case (Map.lookup (VarName name) sInnerEnvFun) of
        Nothing -> put ( ( envOut, ((Map.insert (VarName name) (DefFun  (VarName name) args typ begin statements end) sInnerEnvFun), sInnerEnvEVal)) ) >>= \_ -> return ()
        (Just x) -> throwError  "ee"
```

Hi, I cannot understand why `get` and `put` functions can be called? How the Haskell know "where" is state? I have a problem in favour of imperative programming- after all, such function we have to call on object ( as method) or pass state by argument.

Comment: well welcome again - I think we know you (no need to create a new account ;) ) - Haskell knows it from the context you are in - think of it like this: `put` is more like a place-holder - an action - and `>>=` connects it with the rest of the computation - that's how it know - because it's used wiht a `>>=` of a certain type (or in a `do` block with a certain type) ... - the details are a bit more complex but probably not important to understand it

Comment: It helps me to think of `StateT` as a *plan* to execute with `runStateT`, rather than something that you do *now*. `get` and `put` are just steps in that *plan*, and not functions that interact with the state *now*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `State` monad functions `get` and `put` and sequence them with `do` notation or `>>=`, you are constructing a "recipe" (often called an "action") for accessing and modifying local state that will eventually be used with some particular state. For example:

```
increment = do
  count <- get
  put (count + 1)
```

This action can then be used with the part of the `State` interface that lets you run actions by passing in a state. We will use `execState`, which returns the state and discards the other value, to demonstrate:

```
> execState increment 1
2
```

`execState` is what connects the action `increment` with the state it modifies. `increment` by itself doesn't contain any state, it is just a recipe for interacting with state that you must evaluate later.

Answer (score 1):

The `State` type (which `StateT` is a generalization of) is implemented something like this:

```
newtype State s a = 
    State { -- A function that takes a state of type `s` and 
            -- produces a pair `(a, s)` of a result of type 
            -- `a` and a new state of type `s`.
            runState :: s -> (a, s) 
          }
```

This type has instances for `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad` that allow you to assemble complex `State` values out of simpler ones:

```
-- I won't write the code for these here
instance Functor (State s) where ...
instance Applicative (State s) where ...
instance Monad (State s) where ...
```

Basically, `State` is a shortcut for chaining functions of types that look like `s -> (a, s)`, but without having to pass around those `s` values explicitly.  When you're ready to actually "feed" a `State` action with an `s` value you use one of these operations (depending on which part of the result you want):

```
runState  :: State s a -> s -> (a, s)
evalState :: State s a -> s -> a
execState :: State s a -> s -> s
```

What `put` and `get` do, then, is interact with the "hidden" state argument that the `State` type implicitly passes around in your code.  Their implementations are something like this:

```
get :: State s s
get = State (\s -> (s, s))

put :: s -> State s ()
put s = State (\_ -> ((), s))
```

And that's it!